# How to group list of media by parent in Umbraco

Tags: asp.net, umbraco

Our page displays monthly factsheets (PDF) attached to it as Media in Umbraco, and the Media are grouped by year. The script (with IDs of factsheets as input) displays each year with monthly factsheets grouped in one div.

Problem is that the year for grouping is now taken from "date" property. But it takes some time to make the factsheet, so eg December factsheet has date of January 15th. I thought I could just replace

```
x => x.GetPropertyValue<DateTime>("date").Year
```

with

```
x => x.Parent.Name
```

but it doesn't seem to be the right way, although it works fine with eg

```
@(file.Parent.Name)
```

in the last loop. Thanks, I'm really a beginner in ASP.NET!

```
IList<IPublishedContent> files = ((IEnumerable<IPublishedContent>) (Umbraco
    .Media(factsheetIdsString.Split(new[] {','}))
    .OrderBy("date desc")));

@foreach (IGrouping<int, IPublishedContent> yearGroup in files.GroupBy(x => x.GetPropertyValue<DateTime>("date").Year)) {
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <h2>@yearGroup.Key factsheets</h2>
        <ul>
        @foreach (IPublishedContent file in yearGroup) {
            <li>File @(file.Name) from folder @(file.Parent.Name)</li>
        }
        </ul>
    </div>
}
```

Comment: I don't get what you are trying to do or what the problem is.

Comment: So I have a bunch of media, PDF factsheets produced monthly. I was trying to **group** the list of files by year, but instead of getting the date from the media's property, I was trying to use the folder it's in.

Comment: What version of Umbraco are you using?

Comment: Umbraco version 7.1.4